# Golang reference to slice field in array of types

Tags: go

I'm a Python programmer enjoying Go. The thing that trips me up must often is the use of references; I have mastered it (mostly) but then on occasion something baffles me, such as this one.

I have a simple type ('Fixture'):

```
type Fixture struct {
    Probabilities      *[]float64
}
```

If I populate the Probabilities field for a single instance of this type, everything is fine:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
f := Fixture{}
p := []float64{}
p = append(p, 0.5)
p = append(p, 0.2)
p = append(p, 0.3)
f.Probabilities = &p
c.Infof("%v", *f.Probabilities)

2013/03/19 07:37:36 INFO: [0.5 0.2 0.3]
```

However if I try and populate this field for an array of these types, the code compiles but the field value is always nil:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
fixtures := []Fixture{}
f := Fixture{}
fixtures = append(fixtures, f)
for _, f := range fixtures {
    p := []float64{}
    p = append(p, 0.5)
    p = append(p, 0.2)
    p = append(p, 0.3)
    f.Probabilities = &p
}
for _, f := range fixtures {
    // c.Infof("%v", *f.Probabilities) // causes error
    c.Infof("%v", f.Probabilities)
}

2013/03/19 07:37:41 INFO: <nil>
```

I guess I'm not understanding how arrays/slices work, particularly with respect to references. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: p.s. there doesn't seem to be a point to your using a pointer to a slice. Just use a slice directly.

Comment: 1: You don’t have to use a pointer to a slice here. Slices are references to actual arrays. 2: You’re actual problem (as jnml and PeterSo wrote here) is that `f` in range is a copy and changing that does not change slice elements. 3: Why not make a function for creating new `Fixture`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the range statement

```
for _, f := range fixtures { ... }
```

`f` is a newly declared local variable of type `Fixture`. It's not a *reference* to anything. So after setting up its values, it has to be put into to the `fixtures` slice.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Fixture struct {
        Probabilities *[]float64
}

func main() {
        fixtures := []Fixture{}
        f := Fixture{}
        fixtures = append(fixtures, f)
        for i, f := range fixtures {
                p := []float64{}
                p = append(p, 0.5)
                p = append(p, 0.2)
                p = append(p, 0.3)
                f.Probabilities = &p
                fixtures[i] = f
        }
        for _, f := range fixtures {
                fmt.Printf("%v", f.Probabilities)
        }
}
```

(Also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/rTbjZwzO4y))

---

Output

```
&[0.5 0.2 0.3]
```

Comment: Alternatively, make a slice of pointers `[]*Fixture` so that range will copy the pointer, but it still points to the original slice element.

Comment: example for what @ThomasKappler said https://go.dev/play/p/o24xl9fv7Bm